# Send an image with flask by using urllib2

Tags: python, flask, urllib2

I'm new to [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and I want to send an image to a client that was previously received from a external server with urllib2. Here is my example code for sending the google logo to the client:

```
import urllib2
from flask import Flask, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/getTestImage')
def getTestImage():

    url = "https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png"

    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    img = response.read()
    response.close()

    return img

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I open `127.0.0.1:5000/getTestImage` with a browser ( e.g. Firefox) I just get binary code. How do I send the png file so that the browser display the image? I found `send_file` from `Flask` but I don't realy know how to use the function with the received image data from urllib2.

**Edit:** I figured it out. Simply `return Response(img, mimetype="image/png")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see binary data because you're returning the image data directly.  Flask wraps text returned from a view in its [default `Response` object, which sets the mimetype to `text/plain`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/0.10.1/flask/wrappers.py#L184).  Since you're not returning plain text data, you need to create a response that describes the correct mimetype.

```
return app.response_class(img, mimetype='image/png')
```